# How to find directories older than date when the date is encoded to dirname as yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-findutils

I want to purge old folders with all the content by GNU find. I'm familiar with `-mtime` but the time stamp of the directories is usually corrupted by rsync - not important. Luckily, the time stamp is encoded to the directory name as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

How can I do the same by using the dirname instead of time stamp? Optimal read solution is preferred.

EDIT:
Corrupted time stamps:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 8192 Aug 23 11:12 2016-05-03
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 8192 Aug 23 11:12 2016-05-04
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 8192 Aug 23 11:12 2016-05-05
```

The files inside the dirs have **correct** time stamps.

1. idea: purge the files with `find -mtime` and then (second round) purge the empty dirs. Most likely it is not possible to perform both in one round, since `-empty` would apply to files as well.
2. idea: fix the time stamps of the directories in one round (according to their name) and then purge all by `find -mtime` in another round. But the regular rsync will corrupt that again. The cron jobs must be tuned against race conditions.
3. idea: convert `-mtime +150` to `yyyy-mm-dd` (using `date -d "-150 days"`) and then compare this string with the folder name, as it was suggested in the answer by @xvan

I ask for help finding the best way.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). — I would just read the folder names, split it using `${name#-}` into day, month, year and then compare the dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use bash lexicographical compare:

```
if [[ "2010-01-01" < "2011-02-02" ]]
  then echo "yes"
fi
```

---

EDIT: It's a bit hard to escape `<`, this worked for me.

```
find . ! -path . -type d -exec bash -c "[[ {} < 2010-02-02 ]]"  \; -print
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right way, combining with my nr.3 idea it does the job. The final command is: `find . ! -path . -type d -exec bash -c "[[ {} < $(date -d "-30 days" +%Y-%m-%d) ]]"  \; -print`. Thank you.